# Finding a transformation that yields a prescribed PDF

Tags: continuity, random-variables, transformation, function-and-relation-composition

I am attempted to procure a function from a composition when given the PDF (I typed the full problem at the bottom in its entirety in case I left out details in my inquiry).

I understand how to get the PDF of a transformed uniformly distributed RV, $X=\phi \circ U$, which can be expression as following:
$$\frac{dP_x}{dx} = \frac{du}{dx} = \frac{1}{\phi'(\phi'(x))}$$

However, I am getting confused with regards to reversing this process.  The target PDF will be a function of the transformation, I believe. So, after separating the variables and integrating both sides, I would need so solve the following equation (I can't figure out if there are bounds or not, or if I am solving it correctly):
$$u=\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x} dx \text{ or }u=\int e^{-x} dx$$

Then, I would need to actually find $x=\phi(u)$ by solving the resulting equation.  My next question would be how I would figure out the integration constant in this case?

I believe I am just missing a small concept that would allow me to fully understand how to solve this problem.  Any help or guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated!

---

Full Problem:

Suppose that $U$ is a standard unit random variable that is uniformly distributed on the real interval $[0,1)$.  Find a function $\phi(u)$ such that the transformed RV, $X=\phi \circ U$ will have the following probability density function on the interval $[0,+\infty)$:
$$p_X(x)=e^{-x}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I admit the following response is a bit sloppy, so scrutiny is very much appreciated.

I would say take a guess and suppose we have a one-to-one relationship. Then
it must be the case that
$$e^{-x} = \frac{f_U(u)}{\left|\frac{dx}{du}\right|} = \frac{1}{\left|\frac{dx}{du}\right|} = \left|\frac{du}{dx}\right|$$
I think you can drop the absolute value since $e^{-x}$ is positive.
Hence we have
$$du = e^{-x}\,dx\implies\int\,du =\int e^{-x}\,dx\implies u = e^{-x}$$
where I think you can ignore the constant of integration since $e^{-x}$ is a density. Also, it is an indefinite integral since
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx = 1.$$
Thus we have that
$$X = -\log U.$$

You can check that this is the correct transformation using a one-to-one change of variable, or the cdf approach by calculating
$$P(X \leq x) = P(-\log U \leq x).$$

Comment: I understand asserting that $e^{-x}=\frac{du}{dx}$.  Where I don't understand is how the indefinite integral fits in to all of this.  I think you are right about the integration constant due to the fact that your equation keeps the function distributed on the real interval $[0,1)$ for $[0,+\infty)$.  Is that what you were trying to prove with the indefinite integral?  That it was still bounded?

Comment: @E.Otero I used indefinite integral since I have to 'undo' the derivative I took to get $\left|\frac{du}{dx}\right|$ It has to be indefinite. It doesn't make sense to take $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx$ since it is equal to $1$.

Comment: Isn't the integral of $e^{-x}$ equal to $-e^{-x}$?

Comment: @E.Otero Yes, that was a typo. But I did forget it in the final answer. The transformation is correct.